# Splash screen displaying whenever app comes to foreground

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Splash screen is displaying whenever app comes to foreground. can anyone help me?

Comment: That implies the app was not running at the time, and is being launched anew.  This should be easily verified by logging a message in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and checking for it when "coming to the foreground".

Comment: What are you using   for showing splash  Screen?

Comment: Imageview in Launch screen Storyboard

Comment: This Problem occurs even after navigating to some other view. If I minimize and re-enter there is a splashscreen